# Text undefined - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, visual-studio-code, chatbot

I'm currently making a chatbot for a school project. 
So basically what I want is for the chatbot to send a copy of a certain message from the user's input to another channel. But when I run my code it returns the value as undefined. My code looks like the following:

```
bot.on('message', data => {
    if (data.type !== 'message' || data.subtype === 'bot_message') {
        return;
    }
    findClassroomMention(data.text);
});

var classrooms = 
    {
        L108: ["L108","108"],
        L208: ["L208","208"]
    };


function findClassroomMention(message) {    
    var found = false   
    for(var ClassroomId in classrooms) {
        for(var term of classrooms[ClassroomId]) {
            if(message.includes(term)) {
                found = ClassroomId;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            notifyProblemSolver();
            break;
        }
    }
    return found
};

function notifyProblemSolver(ClassroomId) {
    const params = {
        icon_emoji: ':smiley:'
    }
    bot.postMessageToChannel('caris','We have a problem in ' + ClassroomId, params);
};
```

For example the user's input is:

> Hi I have a problem in classroom L108

Then I want the chatbot to send a message to the problemsolver containing the value L108, like this:

> We have a problem in L108

But when I run the code it sends L108 as undefined:

> We have a problem in undefined

Comment: You are not passing the found ClassroomId to notifyProblemSolver method, you are calling the method with no parameters, which will make the parameter inside the method "undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass the `ClassroomId` in `notifyProblemSolver()`

**Problem**

```
if (found) {
    // You forgot to pass the ClassroomId
    notifyProblemSolver();
    break;
}
```

**Solution**

```
if (found) {
    // Add the ClassroomId
    notifyProblemSolver(ClassroomId);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I can see, `notifyProblemSolver` function is only called in

```
if (found) {
  notifyProblemSolver();
  break;
}
```

If you don't pass any arguments to the function call it, your ClassroomId parameter will be undefined in that specific call. I think what you meant to do was pass found to it like:

```
if (found) {
  notifyProblemSolver(found);
  break;
}
```